# Categories REST API relation with Blog Posts

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8

I am new to Drupal.
I am trying to create a news app with Drupal as back end.
I created a Category Taxonomy and attached it with Articles Content type.
Then I created View for Articles Rest api and I am successfully getting all the content. You can see here - [Link](https://api.irresistiblemt.in/dpl1/rest/v1/articles)

Then I created a new Rest Api View for Categories with is also returning List of Categories. [Link](https://api.irresistiblemt.in/dpl1/rest/v1/categories)

**1.** The problem is how can I link both ? So I can return the list of
    posts in categories when user click on a category name.

**2.** I also want to show the list of categories and when someone click on a category, it should return all the posts of that category.

**This is something relationship issue. How can I achieve this ? I am new in Drupal. Please help.**

Comment: Can anyone help me??? 

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add an extra field in your views and render the URL to content as a result of it.

( add title field, in the formatter section, chose URL )

let me know if you don't know how to create link to content view field.